# AC Diode Question

Tags: diodes, ac, relay

I am a noob in electrical circuit boards. I need to build a basic circuit board that allows me to open 2 valves at a time but the current should not flow to open an other valve down the circuit if that makes sense.

I tried to explain this in my diagram below.

If I switch on SW1 it should open valve3 and valve2 but valve1 should stay off.
If I switch on SW2 it should open valve1 and valve2 but valve3 should stay off.

I can only think of a diode or perhaps a normally closed relay to stop the current to flow to the other valve. I am not so sure about the diode as it is AC Power.

FYI This is just a default diagram so the diode 1N4148 is probably wrong. Also the source power will be the same device it is just easier to explain the layout by making it look like two.

Please let me know how I can do this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQtX07.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Diodes will **not** do what you want, at least not in any kind of useful way.

Comment: What's the voltage rating of your valves?

Comment: what if you switch both switches?

Comment: The Solenoid valves will be normal irrigation valves 24 VAC 50/60 Hz (cycles per second) solenoid power requirement:
0.30 A (7.2 VA) inrush current; 0.23 A (5.5 VA) holding current
Solenoid coil resistance: 38 Ohms

Comment: if i switch on both switches it should then open all valves , but that should not be the case as the switch doesn't allow that

Comment: You can't really use diode to switch AC.  You'd be better off perhaps with a relay (or two).  Can you edit your question with a logic diagram?

Comment: Yep, a very strictly formal description of what you want to do would be super helpful; also "the power sources will be the same device; I just wanted to make it easier to explain" doesn't work, because, well, it doesn't mean the same thing when you draw to independent sources as when you draw one. That's like meaning "automatic paper folding machine" and saying "table", because it's easier to explain what a table does...

Comment: Use double pole switches.

Comment: double pole switches could do the trick or 2 relays i will try to draw a double pole switches diagram and see if that will work

Comment: Just use a double pole switch with a centre off position.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6qmYK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A double-pole switch or relay solution.*

If you review your schematic you will find a few problems. You have two independent AC supplies where in fact you probably only have one. You have no return path from the solenoids other than through another series-connected solenoid. The diodes don't allow AC through.

Figure 1 shows that each valve shares a common line with the AC supply. Closing SW1 in the left position turns on Valve 1 and Valve 2. Closing SW1 in the right position energises Valve 3 and Valve 2. Centre position is all off. You can replace the switches with two 2-pole relays if that suits your application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5kFb.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Alternative approach.*

If you only have single-pole switches available then you can control the relays as shown here. In this case SW7 overrides SW8 if both are switched on. This time the diodes work because we are switching DC current. The snubber diodes on RLY1 to 3 have been omitted to reduce clutter but should be added to protect the switch contacts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcHa0W.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. If only single-throw switches are available then RLY1 can provide the interlock required. Note that again SW7 will override SW8.*